# Form validates but won't submit data to database table

Tags: php, forms, validation, phpmyadmin, html-table

I'm working on this project and it's pretty much finished, it's a form that validates if the user submits invalid data, but for some reason the data won't store in the table and therefore won't get posted back to the screen, I'm just wondering if anybody could spot where I'm going wrong as I've been looking at it for over an hour. Thanks a lot.

Below is my code:

index.php

```
<!Doctype html public>
<body>
<table cellpadding="5">
<td>
<h1> Games Club Website</h1>
<form action="process.php" method = "post"> 

 <tr>
                    <td class="label">
                        <label for="firstName">
                            First name
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text"
                               name="firstName"
                               id="firstName"
                               value="<?php
                                      if (isset($validator))
                                          echo $validator->getValue('firstName');
                                      ?>"
                        />
                        <span class="error">
                            <?php
                            if (isset($validator))
                                echo $validator->getError('firstName');
                            ?>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>






                 <tr>
                    <td class="label">
                        <label for="lastName">
                           Surname
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text"
                               name="lastName"
                               id="lastName"
                               value="<?php
                                      if (isset($validator))
                                          echo $validator->getValue('lastName');
                                      ?>"
                        />
                        <span class="error">
                            <?php
                            if (isset($validator))
                                echo $validator->getError('lastName');
                            ?>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>







                     <tr>
                    <td class="label">
                        <label for="email">
                           Email Address
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text"
                               name="email"
                               id="email"
                               value="<?php
                                      if (isset($validator))
                                          echo $validator->getValue('email');
                                      ?>"
                        />
                        <span class="error">
                            <?php
                            if (isset($validator))
                                echo $validator->getError('email');
                            ?>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>







                     <tr>
                    <td class="label">
                        <label for="age">
                           Age
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text"
                               name="age"
                               id="age"
                               value="<?php
                                      if (isset($validator))
                                          echo $validator->getValue('age');
                                      ?>"
                        />
                        <span class="error">
                            <?php
                            if (isset($validator))
                                echo $validator->getError('age');
                            ?>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>



<tr>
                    <td class="label">
                        <label>
                            Gender
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="genderMale">Male</label>
                        <input type="radio"
                               name="gender"
                               id="genderMale"
                               value="Male"
                               <?php
                               if (isset($validator))
                                   echo $validator->isChecked("gender", "Male");
                               ?>
                        />

                        <label for="genderFemale">Female?</label>
                        <input type="radio"
                               name="gender"
                               id="genderFemale"
                               value="Female"
                               <?php
                               if (isset($validator))
                                   echo $validator->isChecked("gender", "Female");
                               ?>
                        />
                        <span class="error">
                            <?php
                            if (isset($validator))
                                echo $validator->getError('gender');
                            ?>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>







                <tr>
                    <td class="label">
                        <label>
                            What is your preferred gaming platform?
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="consoleXbox">Xbox 360</label>
                        <input type="radio"
                               name="console"
                               id="consoleXbox"
                               value="Xbox 360"
                               <?php
                               if (isset($validator))
                                   echo $validator->isChecked("console", "Xbox 360");
                               ?>
                        />

                          <label for="consolePs3">Playstation 3</label>
                          <input type="radio"
                               name="console"
                               id="consolePs3"
                               value="PS3"
                               <?php
                               if (isset($validator))
                                   echo $validator->isChecked("console", "PS3");
                               ?>

                        <label for="consoleWii">Nintendo Wii</label>
                        <input type="radio"
                               name="Console"
                               id="consoleWii"
                               value="Wii"
                               <?php
                               if (isset($validator))
                                   echo $validator->isChecked("console", "Wii");
                               ?>
                        />
                        <span class="error">
                            <?php
                            if (isset($validator))
                                echo $validator->getError('console');
                            ?>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>



                 <tr>
                    <td class="label">
                        <label for="password1">
                           Enter a password:
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="password"
                               name="p1"
                               id="p1"
                               value="<?php
                                      if (isset($validator))
                                          echo $validator->getValue('p1');
                                      ?>"
                        />
                        <span class="error">
                            <?php
                            if (isset($validator))
                                echo $validator->getError('p1');
                            ?>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>




                 <tr>
                    <td class="label">
                        <label for="p2">
                           Confirm password:
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="password"
                               name="p2"
                               id="p2"
                               value="<?php
                                      if (isset($validator))
                                          echo $validator->getValue('p2');
                                      ?>"
                        />
                        <span class="error">
                            <?php
                            if (isset($validator))
                                echo $validator->getError('p2');
                            ?>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit"
                               name="submitButton"
                               id="submitButton"
                               value="Confirm Registration" />

                        <input type="reset"
                               name="resetButton"
                               id="resetButton"
                               value="Clear Data"
                               style="margin-right: 20px;" />
                    </td>
                </tr>




</form>


</td>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Process.php

```
<?php

require_once "FormValidator.php";

$validator = new FormValidator();

if ($validator->validate($_POST)) {
    require 'dao.php';
}
else {
    require 'index.php';
}


?>
```

FormValidator.php

```
<?php
class FormValidator {
    private $valid;
    private $errors;
    private $data;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->valid = TRUE;
        $this->errors = array();
        $this->data = NULL;
    }

    public function validate($data) {
        $this->data = $data;

        if (empty($data['firstName'])) {
            $this->valid = FALSE;
            $this->errors['firstName'] = 'A <u>First Name</u> is required<br/>';
        }
        if (empty($data['lastName'])) {
            $this->valid = FALSE;
            $this->errors['lastName'] = 'A <u>Surname</u> is required.<br/>';
        }
        if (empty($data['p1'])) {
            $this->valid = FALSE;
            $this->errors['p1'] = 'A <u>Password</u> is required.<br/>';
        }
        if (empty($data['console'])) {
            $this->valid = FALSE;
            $this->errors['console'] = 'Please choose a <u>Console</u>.<br/>';
            }
        if (empty($data['p2'])) {
            $this->valid = FALSE;
            $this->errors['p2'] = 'Please <u>Confirm</u> password.<br/>';
        }
        if (empty($data['age'])) {
            $this->valid = FALSE;
            $this->errors['age'] = 'Please enter your <u>Age</u>.<br/>';
        }
         else if (!$this->isValidIntegerInRange($data['age'], 18, 100)) {
            $this->valid = FALSE;
            $this->errors['age'] = 'Invalid age. You also need to be at least 18 to sign up.<br/>';            
        }
        if (empty($data['email'])) {
            $this->valid = FALSE;
            $this->errors['email'] = 'Please enter a valid <u>email address</u>.<br/>';
        }
        else if (!$this->isValidEmail($data['email'])) {
            $this->valid = FALSE;
            $this->errors['email'] = 'Incorrect format (name@website.something is required)<br/>';            
        }
        if (empty($data['p2'])) {
            $this->valid = FALSE;
            $this->errors['p2'] = 'Please <u>Confirm</u> password.<br/>';
        }
        if (!empty($data['p1'])
                && !empty($data['p2'])
                && $data['p1'] !== $data['p2']) {
            $this->valid = FALSE;
            $this->errors['p2'] = 'Error, passwords <u>do not match</u> .<br/>';
        }
        if (empty($data['gender'])) {
            $this->valid = FALSE;
            $this->errors['gender'] = '<u>Please select a Gender.<u>';
        }

        return $this->valid;
    }

    public function getError($key) {
        $error = "";
        if (isset($this->errors[$key])) {
            $error = $this->errors[$key];
        }
        return $error;
    }

    public function getValue($key) {
        $value = "";
        if (isset($this->data[$key])) {
            $value = $this->data[$key];
        }
        return $value;
    }

    public function isChecked($key, $value) {
        $checked = "";
        if (isset($this->data[$key]) && $this->data[$key] === $value) {
            $checked = ' checked="checked"';
        }
        return $checked;
    }

    public function isSelected($key, $value) {
        $selected = "";
        if (isset($this->data[$key]) && $this->data[$key] === $value) {
            $selected = ' selected="selected"';
        }
        return $selected;
    }

    private function isValidEmail($email) {
        return (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== FALSE);
    }

     protected function isValidIntegerInRange($integer, $min, $max) {
        $options = array(
            'options' => array(
                'min_range' => $min,
                'max_range' => $max,
            )
        );
        return (filter_var($integer, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $options) !== FALSE);
    }

}
?>
```

dao.php

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

//Make connection to the database
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "my_db";
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database";


TRY {
$conn = new PDO( $dsn, $username, $password );
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
    $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $console = $_POST['console'];
    $p1 = $_POST['p1'];
    $p2 = $_POST['p2'];


    if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
        //Updates the record
        $id = $_POST['id'];

        $sql = "UPDATE userprofile2 SET"
            . "firstName=".$conn->quote($fname)
            . "lastName=".$conn->quote($lastName)
            . "email=".$conn->quote($email)
            . "age=".$conn->quote($age)
            . "gender=".$conn->quote($gender)
            . "console=".$conn->quote($console)
            . "p1=".$conn->quote($p1)
            . "p2=".$conn->quote($p2)
            . "WHERE id = ".$conn->quote($id);
        $userprofile2 = $conn->query($sql);
    } else {

        // Inserts new values into table
        $sql = "INSERT INTO userprofile2(firstName, lastName, email, age, gender, console, p1, p2"
            . " ) VALUES ("
            . $conn->quote($firstName).","
            . $conn->quote($lastName).","
            . $conn->quote($email).","
            . $conn->quote($age).","
            . $conn->quote($gender).","
            . $conn->quote($console).","
            . $conn->quote($p1).","
            . $conn->quote($p2) . ")";
        $userprofile2 = $conn->query($sql);
    }
} elseif (isset($_GET['ID'])) {

    // edit mode, allows user to change a selected parameter in the table (Not working)
    $userEditDataRows = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM userprofile2 WHERE ID ='.$conn->quote($_GET['ID']));
    if (sizeof($userEditDataRows)>0) {
       // $row = $userEditDataRows[0];
        $firstName = $row['firstName'];
        $lastName = $row['lastName'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $age = $row['age'];
        $gender = $row['gender'];
        $console = $row['console'];
        $console = $row['p1'];
        $console = $row['p2'];
        $ID = $_GET['ID'];
    }

} else {
    //Set the empty values for fields that haven't been filled in
    $firstName = '';
    $lastName = '';
    $email = '';
    $age = '';
    $gender = '';
    $console = '';
    $p1 = '';
    $p2 = '';
    $ID = false;
}
    //construct the table
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM userprofile2";
    $userprofile2 = $conn->query($sql);
    $table = '<table>';
    $table .= '<tr>';
    $table .= '<th>  ID  </th>
               <th>  First Name  </th>
               <th>  Last Name  </th>
               <th>  Email Address  </th>
               <th>  Age  </th>
               <th>  Gender  </th>
               <th>  Console  </th>
               <th>  Password  </th>
               <th>  Password (Confirmed)  </th>';

    $table .= '</tr>';
    foreach ($userprofile2 as $userprofile2) {

        $table .= '  <tr>';
        $table .= '  <td>' . $userprofile2['id'] ." ".  '</td>';
        $table .= '  <td>' . $userprofile2['firstName'] . '</td>';
        $table .= '  <td>' . $userprofile2['lastName'] . '</td>';
        $table .= '  <td>' . $userprofile2['email'] . '</td>';
        $table .= '  <td>' . $userprofile2['age'] . '</td>';
        $table .= '  <td>' . $userprofile2['gender'] . '</td>';
        $table .= '  <td>' . $userprofile2['console'] . '</td>';
        $table .= '  <td>' . $userprofile2['p1'] . '</td>';
        $table .= '  <td>' . $userprofile2['p2'] . '</td>';
        $table .= '  </tr> ';
    }

    $table .= '</table>';

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    exit("Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage());
    //catches errors and prints them to screen
}
?>

<h2>Thank you <?php echo $_POST["firstName"]; // confirmation of a successful
 //entry ?>, your details have been stored!<br /></h2>
<u><h1>Here are the contents of your database:</h1></u>
<?php echo $table ?>

</br>

<a href="index.php">Click Here</a> to go back to the form. </br>

<html>
<body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is `$_POST['id']`. It's not defined anywhere so it doesn't get the chance to insert because of the following code block:

`if (isset($_POST['id'])) {`

Try using `$_GET['id']` instead:

`if (isset($_GET['id'])) {`